# Python "ValueError: could not convert string to float: %"

Tags: python, string, function, valueerror

I have a set of instructions:

Create a function called `format_change` which takes a string such as those in the Change column and does the following:

- If the last character is a `%` sign, remove it
- convert the string to a **float**
- if that float is positive, multiply it by 100
- return the resulting **float**

This is my code:

```
def format_change(string):
    if string[-1] == "%":
        string = string[-1]

    str_as_float = float(string)

    if str_as_float > 0:
        str_as_float = str_as_float * 100

return str_as_float
```

yet, when I enter the function

```py
format_change(0.45%)
```

It returns the output:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '%'

What can I do to convert it properly?

Comment: Check how slicing works [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp). Also you could use `str.replace('%','')` to remove the `%` sign.

Comment: That's Another good way! I'll be sure to use that next time. would've saved me  precious time. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the string `'%'` to your variable, but you want everything except that character. Change the beginning of your function to:

```
def format_change(string):
    if string[-1] == "%":
        string = string[:-1]  # added ':'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def format_change(string):
    if string[-1] == "%":
        string = string[:-1]
    
    str_as_float = float(string)

    if str_as_float > 0:
        str_as_float = str_as_float * 100

    return str_as_float


print(format_change('0.45%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Solution 1**:

```
def format_change(string):
    if string.endswith("%"):
        string = string[0:-1]

    str_as_float = float(string)
    if str_as_float > 0:
        str_as_float = str_as_float * 100
    return str_as_float

print(format_change('-0.45%'))
```

**Solution 2**:

```
def format_change(string):
   if string.endswith('%'):
       return abs(float(string[0:-1]))*100

print(format_change('-0.45%'))
```

**Solution 3**:

```
def format_change(string):
    return abs(float(string.split('%')[0]))*100

print(format_change('-0.45%')
```

**Output**:

```
45.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are lookign for a one liner you can use this:

```
def format_change(string):
    return float(string.replace('%',''))*100 if float(string.replace('%',''))>0 else float(string.replace('%',''))
```

```
format_change("-50%")
# -50.0
format_change("50%")
# 5000.0
```